# Safari windows debugging symbols

Tags: debugging-symbols, safari

Apple developer network site has a small guide about [setting up debugging symbols server for Safari browser on Windows](https://developer.apple.com/internet/safari/windows_symbols_instructions.html).  But it doesn't work. First, the link to actual symbols server 
gets redirected from http to https, but then it just 404s. 
Now, I know that Safari isn't supported on Windows any longer, but I wanted to play with existing version. Any idea if the symbols are actually available somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to contact Adam Roben directly for the symbol files. He seems to be the person who put these out 5 years ago.

You can find his email and some more information regarding symbol server at the following links.
http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/35512 
https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2008-August/004741.html 
http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/Safari-for-Windows-symbol-server-updated-td177872.html

Comment: yes, i guess that is my best chance as i doubt anybody else god them , thank you!